# OpenAPI generate spring from swagger with "oneof" property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I read already this thread:
[How to use OpenAPI "oneOf" property with openapi-generator-maven-plugin when generating Spring code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760156/how-to-use-openapi-oneof-property-with-openapi-generator-maven-plugin-when-gen)

But I still cant find a good working solution to generate Spring capable models from Swagger file with "oneof" properties.

I tried:

```
java -jar .\openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i ./swagger.json -o ./spring-gen -g spring -c .\spring-config.json
```

with spring-config.json:

```
{
"legacyDiscriminatorBehavior":false
}
```

Did I miss something to get it working?
Is there a better/easy solution to get the models?

Open for any hints and thanks in advance!

Kind regards
Gregor