# OpenAPI models not being generated when using oneOf

Tags: swagger, polymorphism, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenAPI+OpenAPI-generator with spring boot, and trying to use the schema `oneof` as follows:

This is the configuration in the requests.yaml file:

```
...

requestBody:
 name: request
 required: true
 content:
   application/json:
     schema:
       oneOf:
         - $ref: 'components.yaml#/Request'
         - $ref: 'components.yaml#/ComplexRequest'

...
```

and this is the relevant configuration in the components.yaml file:

```
Request:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/BaseInfo'
    - type: object
      properties:
        should_create:
          type: boolean
          enum: [ false ]
        reference_id:
          type: string
        required:
          - reference_id

ComplexRequest:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/BaseInfo'
    - type: object
      properties:
        should_create:
          type: boolean
          enum: [ true ]
        create_data:
          $ref: '#/Reference'
      required:
        - create_data

BaseInfo:
  type: object
  properties:
    customer_id:
      type: string

Reference:
  type: object
  properties:
    propery_1:
      type: string
    propery_2:
      type: string
    propery_3:
      type: string
```

For some reason, all of these components and only these are not being generated.
Can someone enlighten me on what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possibly this issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10880

Comment: yes, I've also noticed [this](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5903), I really hoped it's not a bug but something I've missed here. :(

Comment: I see that it should be theoretically possible to discriminate a Request from a ComplexRequest at deserialization because of your differing required fields. I have oneOf generation working for java using openapi-generator 5.4.0 but I do add a discriminator field (like requestType: type: string enum: ['COMPLEX']).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is facing this issue, I hope I'll save you some investigation time;
As for March 2022, it seems like `oneOf` (and `anyOf`) is just not supported by openapi-generator:
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/roadmap/#short-term

And though not compatible for my situation, you can try the solutions suggested here:
[How to use OpenAPI "oneOf" property with openapi-generator-maven-plugin when generating Spring code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760156/how-to-use-openapi-oneof-property-with-openapi-generator-maven-plugin-when-gen)